# Entity Too Large on Ubuntu post_max_size being smaller than upload_max_filesize

Tags: apache2, php

So I'm trying to import a xml file on wordpress. When I try to import the file, it gives me the following error.

> Sorry, there has been an error. File is empty. Please upload something
>   more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being
>   disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller
>   than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

I've obviously looked at many of the similar problems but haven't quite solved it. My php.ini config r as follows:

```
memory_limit = 2600M
post_max_size = 2550M
upload_max_filesize = 2600M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

The file size that I'm trying to upload is around 22493KB.

Comment: If the message is generated by WordPress when you interact with WordPress, what does WordPress support have to say?

Comment: Try making post_max_size larger than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: hey @DougSmythies I've tried that too but it still displays that error. I'm just trying to move blogs from old site to new site.

Comment: I wonder if it is actually a 32 bit signed integer, and therefore limited to less than 2,147,483,648 bytes.

Comment: what would you recommend when transferring old blogs to a new site through ubunut/phpmyadmin?